# Dimensionality of result of indexing an ndarray with a slice vs range

Tags: python, numpy, range, slice

I'm trying to understand the use of a `range` as an index, and compare it with the use of a slice as an index, on an `ndarray`. Specifically, the effect on the dimensionality of the result.

What I understand is that:

1. For a given dimension (say, the 0th dimension) of an `ndarray`, if I use a scalar index such as 2, it has the effect that the dimensionality of the result is less than the dimensionality of the original `ndarray`, by 1.
2. For the same (0th) dimension, instead of a scalar 2, if I use `slice(2,3)`, the above-mentioned reduction in dimensionality will not happen.

For the most part, if I use a `range` instead of a `slice`, the effect (on dimensionality) seems to be the same, but for one special case.

Here's the code. The surprise, for me, is in the 4th print statement:

```
import numpy as np

nd15 = np.array([['e00','e01','e02','e03'],
                 ['e10','e11','e12','e13'], 
                 ['e20','e21','e22','e23']])

# Consider the dimensionality of the indexing results from the below 4 
# lines.
# From the first 3 print statements, we are led to believe that, if you
# replace a range with an "equivalent" slice-expression, the
# dimensionality of the result will remain unchanged.
# But the fourth result below surprisingly negates that understanding.
print (nd15[slice(2,3), slice(2,3)].shape)
print (nd15[slice(2,3), range(2,3)].shape)
print (nd15[range(2,3), slice(2,3)].shape)
print (nd15[range(2,3), range(2,3)].shape)
```

I expected the fourth print to also give the same result as the other three.

Instead, this is the result I got:

```
(1, 1)
(1, 1)
(1, 1)
(1,)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are triggering two different types of [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) without realizing it because of the implicit conversion of `range` to an `ndarray`.

When you have a `range` or `list` (or any other iterable really) in both indices, you trigger [integer array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). In this scheme, the result will be the same shape as the broadcasted index arrays. In this case, that's a 1D array because that's what the ranges are converted to.

When one index is iterable and the other a slice, you trigger [a form of hybrid indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing). In this case, the shape has a combination of the dimensions from the advanced index (1) and the slice (1). If you had specified a 2D nested list instead of a `range` for the advanced index, you would have gotten a 3D output.

Comment: thank you. Initially, try as I might, your explanation just didn't sink into my head. I then looked at the links in your explanation. That wasn't easy either, but when I was through, I was able to understand your explanation. I guess all this difficulty was because I thought my learning of indexing was 90% complete, while the reality was that it is a much vaster and deeper subject, and my actual learning had been only about 10% ! Thanks again.

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad you found this to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your slice and range expressions can also be written as:

```
In [86]: nd15[2:3, 2:3]
Out[86]: array([['e22']], dtype='<U3')
In [87]: nd15[2:3, [2]]
Out[87]: array([['e22']], dtype='<U3')
In [88]: nd15[[2],2:3]
Out[88]: array([['e22']], dtype='<U3')
In [89]: nd15[[2],[2]]
Out[89]: array(['e22'], dtype='<U3')
```

`nd15[2,2]` would be the scalar element 'e22'.

But the differences might be clearer if we expand the slices to produce a (2,2) array:

```
In [97]: nd15[1:3, 2:4]
Out[97]: 
array([['e12', 'e13'],
       ['e22', 'e23']], dtype='<U3')
In [98]: nd15[1:3,[2,3]]
Out[98]: 
array([['e12', 'e13'],
       ['e22', 'e23']], dtype='<U3')
In [99]: nd15[[1,2], 2:4]
Out[99]: 
array([['e12', 'e13'],
       ['e22', 'e23']], dtype='<U3')
In [100]: nd15[[1,2], [2,3]]
Out[100]: array(['e12', 'e23'], dtype='<U3')
```

The last one is a diagonal, the (1,2) and (2,3) elements.

`Out[86]` and `Out[97]` are `views`, the rest are copies.